# Symfony 4 flex change exception structure

Tags: php, symfony, apache-flex, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 + Flex and I'm looking for the best way to change the exception structure.

In previous version, when I throw an exception, it was like :

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Your message here"
}
```

from a function like : `throw new HttpException(400, 'Your message here');`

Now with Symfony 4 + Flex, with the same code, I have an exception with all the trace like :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request",
        "exception": [
            {
                "message": "Your message here",
                "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
                "trace": [
                    {
                        "namespace": "",
                        "short_class": "",
                        "class": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "function": "",
                        "file": "/var/www/api-symfony/src/Controller/UserController.php",
                        "line": 45,
                        "args": []
                    },
                    {
                        "namespace": "App\\Controller",
                        "short_class": "UserController",
                        "class": "App\\Controller\\UserController",
                        "type": "->",
                        "function": "getUserByRppsAction",
                        "file": "/var/www/api-symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
                        "line": 149,
                        "args": [
                            [
                                "object",
                                "FOS\\RestBundle\\Request\\ParamFetcher"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
                        "short_class": "HttpKernel",
                        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
                        "type": "->",
                        "function": "handleRaw",
                        "file": "/var/www/api-symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
                        "line": 66,
                        "args": [
                            [
                                "object",
                                "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                            ],
                            [
                                "integer",
                                1
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
                        "short_class": "HttpKernel",
                        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
                        "type": "->",
                        "function": "handle",
                        "file": "/var/www/api-symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php",
                        "line": 190,
                        "args": [
                            [
                                "object",
                                "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                            ],
                            [
                                "integer",
                                1
                            ],
                            [
                                "boolean",
                                true
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
                        "short_class": "Kernel",
                        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
                        "type": "->",
                        "function": "handle",
                        "file": "/var/www/api-symfony/public/index.php",
                        "line": 37,
                        "args": [
                            [
                                "object",
                                "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I clean this error ? I just need to have the code and message...

Thanks !

Edit : In prod mode this is want I have :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

So it's better but I don't have my custom error message...

Comment: Just out of curiosity do you get the exception information in production mode?

Comment: Hum... no ! :) Thanks for that, in prod mode it's like I want

Comment: Not exactly, in prod mode I don't have my custom error message, I will edit my post

Comment: I don't use the rest bundles myself.  I know that some of the FOS stuff is still being updated to support S4.  bin/console debug-eventdispatcher kernel.exception will list the exception handlers.  I would suspect one of them might be from the rest bundle.